# Using @theme to target components in the default theme to use in a custom component

Tags: vue.js, components, themes, vuepress

I'm using Vuepress for documentation and found myself in need of creating a custom page.

To do so I've followed the Vuepress documentation where it was [described](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#custom-layout-for-specific-pages) that you can use YALM front matter to target a different component to use as layout:

```
---
layout: SpecialLayout
---
```

However, when I try to use an existing component from the default theme it seems like I can't import that component.

```
import PageNav from '@theme/components/PageNav.vue'
```

In SpecialLayout.vue does nothing, I can't see it in my custom component.

I prefer not to eject as I want to rely on future updates of the Vuepress default theme.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to create only the files you want to customise (using the existing component paths & names) or create your own and reference them from a custom SpecialLayout file (as in your case)

To make creating custom components easier you can eject and specify a target directory (other than /theme) and then only clone / update what you need to customise.

In your example you would need to create /theme/components/PageNav.vue and /theme/layout/SpecialLayout.vue.

Create all the custom markup for specialLayout as required or Eject/clone the original /theme/layout to be SpecialLayout and replace the navbar references with your custom PageNav component.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback.

I don't want to eject as I see it as minor changes on top of the standard theme. And ejecting would be forfeiting the comfort of updates.

Comment: If you do not intend to make any changes to a component you wish to use, then make sure you reference an existing component from vuepress. PageNav.vue is not in the standard theme components so would not show on your SpecialLayout file.